# DD-WRT Forwarding Specific Mac Address to Different interface

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I have the following IPTable rules:

> iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -d `nvram get lan_ipaddr`/`nvram get lan_netmask` -m state --state NEW -j DROP
>
> iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -j SNAT --to `nvram get lan_ipaddr`

These rules 
1) Allow people connected to the wifi to access the internet 
2) Block people on the wifi from accessing vlan0

I would like to add a rule to allow specific mac addresses access to vlan0 from the wifi (eth1)

I'm having trouble grokking the Iptable syntax, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -i eth1 -o eth0.0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0.0 -j DROP # or REJECT
```